# importing commands from multiple files does not sync all commands

Tags: python, discord.py

so i have a discord bot which is split up into multiple python files that i imported and when i import them into main.py it always only syncs the commands from the last import and disregards all of the rest. these are the imports. (i do have all of the required imports)

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready, you can now leave the tab")
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue())
    channel = client.get_channel(channel id here)
    embed.add_field(name=f'back online',
                    value='bot has been updated',
                    inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"synced {len(synced)} commands")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

from cogs.admin import * 
from cogs.data import *
from cogs.economy import *
from cogs.fun import *
from cogs.gambling import *
from cogs.help import *
from cogs.inventory import *
from cogs.leveling import *
from cogs.market import *
from cogs.polls import *
from cogs.role_colors import *
from cogs.shop import *
from cogs.warnings import *
from cogs.xp_boosters import *

and here is the example code for one of the cogs--------------------------------------------

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("CYKLERBOT is ready, you can now leave the tab")
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"synced {len(synced)} commands")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@client.tree.command(name="say", description = "whats should the bot say")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say = "text")
async def _8ball(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:`enter code here`
        return await interaction.response.send_message("You requre administator permisions to use this command")
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{thing_to_say}')
```

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing what's in those other modules.

Comment: @AKX i gave an example of one of the commands. all of the other cogs are just other commands that work in the same way. the probelm arises due to the sync command at the start of main.py only working on the most recent imported cog.

Comment: So you're saying each of the modules defines a `client`? I think that's your problem.

Comment: Did you load the extensions/cogs? All you're doing right now is importing them and syncing the tree without actually loading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to ambiguities. You probably gave the same class name to all your Cogs and when you use `import *`, you are overwriting the previous import. Using `import *` is a bad practice. I recommend just using `import cogs` and throughout your code refer to it using `cogs.fun.xxx`.

Comment: the imports dont use classes. if thats a thing that i need to add please tell me.

Comment: You need to load your cogs using `await client.add_cog(CogClass(client))`

Comment: can you please give me an example of what the code should like like becasue i still dont completely understand